# Is there a way to mount ReiserFS partition in Windows?

Tags: windows, reiserfs

Is there a good reliable way to mount ReiserFS partitions in Windows? All I found is [YAReG](http://yareg.akucom.de/index.html) but it doesn't really mount a drive so I can't use my [favorite tool for file operations](http://www.farmanager.com/) and, more importantly, it won't understand unicode file names.

Answer (score 2):

There's also [rfstool](http://p-nand-q.com/e/reiserfs.html), but I have not specifically tried this.

Note the following restriction!:

- Access is read-only. I do not intend to change that, at least for the
  time being.
- Journal data is ignored. These tools show the file structure as it is
  ON DISK, right now.

Answer (score 1):

maybe not the most elegant way, but it works for me:

> **[Cooperative Linux](http://www.colinux.org/)** is the first working free and open source method for optimally running Linux on Microsoft Windows natively. More generally, Cooperative Linux (short-named coLinux) is a port of the Linux kernel that allows it to run cooperatively alongside another operating system on a single machine. For instance, it allows one to freely run Linux on Windows 2000/XP/Vista/7.

here's a tutorial: **[Ext3, ReiserFS & XFS in Windows thanks to coLinux](http://polishlinux.org/linux/ext3-reiserfs-xfs-in-windows-thanks-to-colinux/)**

Answer (score 0):

There is [rfsd](http://rfsd.sourceforge.net/) which, as I know, is based on rfstool. Simple enough to use and it mounts as a drive so you can use FAR.

Comment: The last update is from 2005 and it states that it is unstable.

Comment: In fact, probably it does not work anymore on newer versions of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

After [another question on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/111978/are-there-any-reiser-file-system-drivers-for-windows-xp) and a little googling:

- An updated version of rfsd: [http://www.acc.umu.se/~bosse/](http://www.acc.umu.se/%7Ebosse/)
- [RFSGUI](http://www.programmersheaven.com/download/38123/download.aspx): Another GUI for rfstool
- A [total commander plugin](http://www.ghisler.com/plugins.htm)