# Are there any Reiser file system drivers for Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, filesystems, reiserfs

... apart from http://rfsd.sourceforge.net which seems to have been abandoned, and apart from plugins to Total Commander?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/23631/is-there-a-way-to-mount-reiserfs-partition-in-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little googling:

- An updated version: [http://www.acc.umu.se/~bosse/](http://www.acc.umu.se/%7Ebosse/)
- [YAReG](http://yareg.akucom.de/): is a free graphical frontend for [rfstool](http://p-nand-q.com/download/rfstool.html) (written by Gerson Kurz). It provides easy and comfortable read access to your ReiserFS formatted Linux partitions through an user interface familiar from Windows Explorer.
- [RFSGUI](http://www.programmersheaven.com/download/38123/download.aspx): Another GUI for rfstool

But they seems abandoned too

Comment: the acc.umu.se site is periodically updated, and is likely to work. I'd note rfs itself hasn't been updated in a while for obvious reasons

Comment: Thanks for the link to acc.umu.se: the Reiser drivers were updated in Nov 2009 so seems reasonably current. 


Up until now I've been using YAReG. I did manage to crash it once and it's not a file system driver which is really what I'm looking for.